# Вывод div в цикле

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем привет!

```
global $product, $woocommerce_loop;

if ( empty( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] ) ) {
    $woocommerce_loop['loop'] = 0;
}

if ( ! $product || ! $product->is_visible() ) {
    return;
}

$woocommerce_loop['loop']++;

$shop_style = yp_opts('shop_style')=='row'?'row':'grid';
?>

<div <?php post_class( $shop_style=='grid'?'item col-lg-4':'' ); ?>>    
        <?php if($shop_style == 'grid') : ?>
            <div class="game-card" style="background-image: url(<?php the_field('game-card-fon');?>);"></div>
</div>
```

Есть такой кусок кода, он выводит список всех товаров, как сделать так что бы через каждые 6 товаров, выводился еще один div с картинкой например?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделай переменную. Инкремент при каждой итерации цикла. Когда в переменной будет `6`(сделай if) - выводи картинку и обнуляй переменную. И оно опять будет заново прибавлять число. Когда достигнет 6, опять выведет картинку. И так все заново.